# Finagle Thrift NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, thrift, finagle

I´m using Finagle thrift but when I build the server and service

```
  val service = new EchoService$FinagleService(new EchoServiceImpl, new TBinaryProtocol.Factory())

  val server = Thrift.server.serveIface("localhost:8080", service)
```

And I run it I receiving the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.twitter.finagle.server.StackServer.$init$(Lcom/twitter/finagle/server/StackServer;)V
    at com.twitter.finagle.Thrift$Server.<init>(Thrift.scala:417)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60647', transport: 'socket'
    at com.twitter.finagle.Thrift$.server(Thrift.scala:495)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should either call

```
val service = new EchoService$FinagleService(new EchoServiceImpl, new TBinaryProtocol.Factory())
val server = Thrift.server.serve("localhost:8080", service)
```

or

```
val server = Thrift.server.serveIface("localhost:8080", EchoServiceImpl)
```

But I don't think this could resolve the NoSuchMethodError, it seems like a version compatibility problem. I would first check Finagle version and Scrooge version, make sure they are on the same page.